# In Chrome Devtool and webpack project, how to go from console stack trace to original source?

Tags: webpack, google-chrome-devtools, webpack-dev-server, source-maps

I have a webpack/typescript project with source map. My webpack devtool config is `eval-source-map`. In Chrome devtool > sources, I can clearly see and debug the original source code.

However, the error call stacks in the console link to code lines in this format: `at App (webpack-internal:///./src/app/App.tsx:27:26)`. Clicking on that link opens it in a separate tab and the content is an empty page.

I can see in the devtool > sources file tree that the path to the original source files begin with `webpack://`, not `web pack-internal` (though this folder also exists and contain the transpiled files).

There are 2 parts to this question:

1. How do we get Chrome to open the linked code in devtool>sources instead of a new browser tab?
2. How do we get Chrome console to link to the original source files instead of the transpiled one?

Thank you in advance for any hint!